# Bundling Xenforo CSS File?

Tags: xenforo

Xenforo, the style file link is created as follows. Is it possible to optimize this as a single file?

`<link async rel="stylesheet" href="https://***/css.php?css=public%3Anormalize.css%2Cpublic%3Afa.css%2Cpublic%3Acore.less%2Cpublic%3Aapp.less&amp ;s=9&amp;l=8&amp;d=1668370416&amp;k=af056e1fb507ccfa25ecfcd7ee278a3aa6be64d0" />`

I want to minify as a single file. Have you done it before? Do you have any plugin suggestions?